# HttpServletRequest.getCookies(): Array, Why The isHttpOnly() function always return false?

Tags: servlets, cookies, servlet-3.0, httponly

hi I'm trying to have httponly cookies so far this is the code that I've written

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("mycookie", "hi");
    resp.addCookie(cookie);

    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    boolean bol = cookie.isHttpOnly();
    out.println("<br>Cookie is Marked as HttpOnly = " + bol);
    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

        out.println("<br/> From Cookies Array Name is: " 
            + cookies[i].getName());
        out.println("<br/> From Cookies Array Value is: "
            + cookies[i].getValue());
        out.println("<br/> From Cookies Array isHttpOnly: "
            + cookies[i].isHttpOnly());
        }
    }
    out.println("<br/> <br/>");

    cookie.setHttpOnly(false);
    boolean bol1 = cookie.isHttpOnly();
    out.println("<br>Cookie is Marked as HttpOnly = " + bol1);
    Cookie[] cookies1 = req.getCookies();
    if (cookies1 != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies1.length; i++) {
        out.println("<br/> From Cookies Array Name is: "
            + cookies[i].getName());
        out.println("<br/> From Cookies Array Value is: "
            + cookies[i].getValue());
        out.println("<br/> From Cookies Array isHttpOnly: "
            + cookies[i].isHttpOnly());
        }
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Prints

```
    Cookie is Marked as HttpOnly = true
From Cookies Array Name is: mycookie
From Cookies Array Value is: hi
From Cookies Array isHttpOnly: false


Cookie is Marked as HttpOnly = false
From Cookies Array Name is: mycookie
From Cookies Array Value is: hi
From Cookies Array isHttpOnly: false
```

Note that I'm using JBoss 7, and in web.xml config I've added but I think something is missing

```
<session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Comment: AFAIK, the web.xml config only relates to the session cookie (JSESSIONID)...

Comment: @home, So what is the right config ?

Comment: I do not know :-) I just know that the web.xml config does not relate to 'self-made' cookies. Did you check whether the cookie is marked 'HTTP only' after the first round-trip back to the server?

Comment: hmm,the first run nothing appears then I call the url again the output appears, I hope this is what you mean by round-trip :D

Comment: but when you mentioned 'self-made' cookies, I think it makes sense, maybe all the httponly thing is for sessions cookies only. I'll google self-made and see, thanks for your help :D

Comment: Yep, this is what I meant by round-trip. As the cookie itself is just a delimited String in HTTP I guess the application server parses the string only once (when retrieving the request).

Comment: hey please review the new code, interesting output is there. seems something wrong with the cookies array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The browser does **not** send cookie information other than the value, such as httponly, secure, maxage, path, etc back. The browser only sends the cookie value back associated with the cookie name.

You can see it yourself by tracking the HTTP traffic in your webbrowser's developer toolset. Press F12 in Chrome/Firebug/IE9 and open the "Network" or "Net" tab and then explore the request and response headers. You'll see that only the `Set-Cookie` response header contains next to the name=value additional cookie parameters and that the `Cookie` request header only contains the name=value.

Don't worry, the additional cookie parameters are remembered in the browser. If you're unsure, you can always override it by creating a new cookie with the same name and path.

#### See also:

- [RFC6265 - Cookie Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)
- [Wikipedia - HTTP cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Cookie)